# How to install a package using stack?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, package-management, haskell-stack

Using cabal, I could install hakyll with the command:

```
cabal install hakyll
```

How can I do the same thing using stack?

Comment: For those looking to _add a dependency_ (i.e. use another package, like `text`, in your code): [Understanding stack’s model and avoiding its biggest gotcha: **You almost certainly do not want to use `stack install`**](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2018/02/10/an-opinionated-guide-to-haskell-in-2018/#understanding-stacks-model-and-avoiding-its-biggest-gotcha); per [`stack` docs](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#adding-dependencies) you have to hand-edit `package.yaml` to add the package to the `dependencies` section.

Answer (score 58):

```
stack install hakyll
```

`stack` offers a curated set of packages that won't blow your machine up. If you want to check what packages are available, or exactly what version is supported, or on what version of `GHC` you can get it, check out https://www.stackage.org/.

For example, you can get `hakyll 4.6.9.0` right now for both `GHC 7.8.4` and `GHC 7.10.1`. Pretty neat. - [source](https://www.stackage.org/lts-2.20/package/hakyll-4.6.9.0)

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention, Yuan Wang's method works for getting the version of `hakyll` that is not curated into `stackage`. It's up to you what version you need.

Comment: what about installing packages that are only on hackage but not on stackage? Is the preferred method to install `cabal-install` or to download the tarball and `stack install` it?

Comment: I tried **stack install accelerate-examples** and got huge **Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered** which goes recursively when trying to fix it. Couldn't even google what the stack build plans are.

Answer (score 17):

add hakyll in stack.yaml generated by `stack init` or `stack new`

yaml file should look like:

```
flags: {}
packages:
  - '.'
extra-deps:
  - hakyll-4.7.1.0
resolver: lts-2.15
```

after that, run `stack solver` installs it

https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/wiki/stack.yaml

Comment: Probably worth adding that `stack install hakyll` all by itself is probably sufficient to get the desired result.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that this method is typically only done when the desired version of the package is not present in the selected snapshot. I believe the preferred method of package installation for a project is adding it to the `*.cabal` file's `build-depends`, or running `stack install hakyll` to test it out first.

Answer (score 5):

[This documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#adding-dependencies) worked for me

On `package.yaml` add the library under `dependencies`, for example:

```
dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- hakyll # added here
```

Comment: For some reason I feel recent versions of GHC have gotten unnecessarily complicated. I used to be able to use cabal. Now I have to go through all of this mess (and more) to get my old programs to compile.